# Deploying my asp.net

Tags: asp.net, publish

OK.. so i spend the last few days trying to figure out how to deploy an asp.net web form.
Through IIS i can publish it, and it works fine. But! and this may be a stupid question, but im getting desperate here - all the videos says it published in the end - but as far as i can see, its only as a localhost!
Did i misunderstand something, and is it NOT actually published? I need to be able to acces it, on another computer.
Im starting to think i need to publish it through a webhost, or azure or something.

I´m not asking for a complete guide, just a nod in the right direction :)
Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need a web host. You need to publish it **to something**. Tutorials just use IIS on the local machine for convenience, but you need a web host that runs IIS or, more recently, via mono on linux. If you go to another computer on your network and put the IP address of your computer into the address bar, you should be able to view your site there. If you want to access this outside of your network, you still need access to a server that will be accessible to the web.

Comment: Thank you for erasing some of the doubt in my mind.. Im now trying to publish it to azure.

Comment: You'll also be able to know that it's published when you can access it with the domain name that you use when you published it :)